# Numerical method to approximate *all* the solutions of of nonlinear algebraic equation

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, nonlinear-system

Suppose we have a nonlinear algebraic equation (by "algebraic" I mean it does not involve derivatives of the unknown) that does not have unique solution, e.g.
$$\sin(x) = 0 \qquad x\in [-10, 10] $$
We could also think of more general problems
$$\mathcal{N}(x) = 0 \qquad x\in\Omega$$
where $\mathcal{N}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a nonlinear algebraic operator defined on $\Omega$, a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d, d \geq 1$. Also suppose $\Omega$ is "well behaved", e.g. is the closure of an open set.

Are there numerical methods to approximate the whole set of solutions of such equations?
In other words, are there methods to approximate the kernel $K(\mathcal{N}) = \left\{ x\in\Omega: \mathcal{N}(x)=0\right\}$ in the case this is not a singleton?

What if, in addiction, the operator $\mathcal{N}$ is a "blackbox" (i.e. no explicit formula for $\mathcal{N}$ or its gradient are available)?

The best I can think about at the moment is to turn the problem into a minimization problem with objective function:
$$\vert\mathcal{N}(x)\vert \qquad x\in\Omega$$
then run an appropriate optimization algorithm. However this approach is meant to determine one solution rather than a set of solution.

Another aspect of the problem I was considering is the fact that the kernel $K(\mathcal{N})$ may have connected components (that may not be singletons), however I do not know if/how to exploit this information to approach the problem.

Comment: Your example problem has roots $n\pi$, $n\in Bbb Z$. How do you propose to numerically treat/distinguish the roots for $n=10^{17}$ and $10^{17}+2$? And differentiate them from all the non-roots in-between? In floating point they get mapped to the same binary approximation.

Comment: Good point. The example is not good. I think the problem is interesting enough even if we consider only bounded domains (the size of which should not be problematic to handle with floating point arithmetic). I have edited the question.

Comment: If solutions are isolated, running global optimization algorithms for $\min\limits_{x \in \Omega} \| \mathcal{N}(x) \|$ is an okay idea. For example, [DIRECT](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/ybrise/data/talks/msem20080401.pdf) can solve this problem knowing only function values and not using derivatives.